# Eclipse Plugin Development: multipage editor with html extension

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've created a plugin from wizard "Plugin with a mutli tab Editor".

Problem: In Project Configuration if I set the `File Extension` field to `html`, the plugin not works. If I leave it `mpe` (pre-inserted field) or I insert another unknown file extension,  then it works.

What can cause this problem and how can I activate the plugin for html files?

**EDIT:**
Ok, I'll try to describe step by step my problem.

I create a new Plugin Project
[image: new plugin project]

I set project name:

[image: project base settings]

...and the project properties

[image: project properties]

I create a plugin using template "multi page editor"

[image: templates plugin]

Now, I must choose the class names and **File Extension** (mpe is pre-inserted from eclipse, I leave it for now).

[image]

Ok. Eclipse generate all files and a project that works. So, if I test it:

[image: run eclipse]

and I create a test project with a test.mpe files

[image: test project]

I can see 3 tabs (because 3 tabs are configured in template code) and a default icon on file name test.mpe on Project Explorer. **The plugin WORKS!**

Now... I close all and I repeat **EXACTLY** all steps, I using `HTML` instead of `MPE`, I test it and... **there is no tabs and there is no icon**.

[image: test html]

Why? And How can I solve it?

Comment: What "problem" are you referring to?  In what way does it not "work"?

Comment: it not works if I insert "html" in `extensions` attribute of `extension->editor` tag in `plugin.xml` file. If I insert, for example "rrr" or another unknown extension, then it works.

Comment: It not works also if I configure the project with wizard. With `html` still not works. With other extensions (`r1t`, `mpe` etc) then it works.

Comment: Are you saying the file's just not opening in your editor?  Do you already have an HTML editor installed?  Have you checked the Open With context menu on the file to make sure your editor is available?

Comment: No, the file is opened with eclipse as expected, but without multi tab

Comment: This just isn't clear enough.  What SHOULD be happening that isn't?  What's happening INSTEAD?

Comment: @nitind I've edited my question. I hope it's more clear now. Thanks :)

Comment: As I mentioned above, check the file's Open With context menu.  Your new editor may not be the default when there's another one already installed.

Comment: @nitind mmh ok. the problem was there. But how can I force my plugin as default editor? PS: If you want, post the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is not set as the default, and the one you have installed is being chosen instead.  See the full documentation and example at http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html?cp=2_1_1_143 .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what nitind said. So simple solution is right click on your created .html file and select Open with and select the editor plugin you installed to open the .html file. So then the file will be opened in your created editor, but not with the default html editor.